# How to download the older version of Tails?

Tags: tails

I want to download tails-i386-1.2.1.iso for some test, so I checked the official website of Tails where only  link to the newest version Tails 1.2.2, I even change the download link from 1.2.2 to 1.2.1 but still couldn't, can someone tell me where can get it?

Answer (score 5):

You can find older versions of tails at the [`obsolete/`](http://dl.amnesia.boum.org/tails/obsolete/) folder. Version 1.2.1 is at http://dl.amnesia.boum.org/tails/obsolete/tails-i386-1.2.1/.

Comment: I wanted to grab the last 32-bit version (2.12). Alas, there is no longer an `obsolete` directory.